# plugins not working after jquery ajax call,

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a scrollbar plugin, but the plugin is not working after the success ajx call.

I am using this plugin

https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar/

now what happens, this is ajax success call

```
    success: function(data) {
                $("#searchResultsNoShow").hide();
                $("#searchResults").show();
                $('.scrollbar-rail').scrollbar();
}
```

the `.scrollbar-rails` is applied to the element inside the `#searchResults > div` and that `div` has other class along with  `scrollbar-rails` but the scrollbar is not applied, it is even happening for the tooltips plugin which is `tooltipster`

Comment: you have `.scrollbar-rail` in the code, whereas you are suggesting `.scrollbar-rails`.

Comment: basically its a typo, but the css is same